# Move jobs between ttys

Tags: linux, background, tty

Does someone know if it is possible to move a job between ttys?

Example:
Starting a job at ttys004, pressing Ctrl+Z to detach it, typing bg 1 to move it to the background.
Then I want to reach it from example ttys002.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. The programs `screen` or `tmux` are usually used to achieve something like this.

Comment: Good question. I mostly start byobu (a wrapper for tmux/screen) by default, but it would be nice if I can move a running process to the tmuxer when I didn't start it from within byobu. Seems like there is an answer below

Answer (score 3):

don't think it is possible. you can use **screen** if you want processes to de(attach). [For more info](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use screen. But then I need to think before starting a job/process :)

Comment: true. normally one doesn't de(attach) processes. If you have to exit from your shell use **nohup redirecting stdout/stderr**, so that if you want to watch can do **tail/less**

Answer (score 3):

`retty` or `reptyr` could help you.

There is an [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen) on serverfault with more information.

Comment: This should be the marked as the solution. I didn't try it yet, though. I started an update, so I can't install either one of these tools until the upgrade is finished ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After having the job started no it is not possible, though if you start it as a daemon, maybe you could fg it when you switch tty (since it's inherited by `init` there is no reason you could not)